# confused about how to use getContentResolver in android

Tags: android, browser

I'm developing an application which reads browser history.I tried using managedQuery but I just got to know that it is deprecated.I found the following answer on a similiar question

```
Cursor cursor = this.context.getContentResolver().query(Browser.SEARCHES_URI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            final int indexDate = cursor.getColumnIndex(Browser.SearchColumns.DATE);
            final int indexTerm = cursor.getColumnIndex(Browser.SearchColumns.SEARCH);
            String date = cursor.getString(indexDate);
            String term = cursor.getString(indexTerm);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
```

My doubt is,what is the role of the context variable over here? How do I get the Browser's context in that variable?

Comment: Context should be of calling application, not of called. So here you no need of Browser's context.

Comment: I didn't get you,so should I just write getContentResolver instead of this,context.getContextResolver?

Comment: I did that,the reference is turning out to be null